# Docker plugins are not recognized as commands when running without sudo

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, docker-compose, buildx

I'm running

- Ubuntu 20.04.5 LTS
- Docker version 23.0.1, build a5ee5b1

Running the command

```
docker build -t some:other Dockerfile
```

Produces the following output:

```
unknown shorthand flag: 't' in -t
```

And

```
docker build
```

The following:

```
docker: 'buildx' is not a docker command.
```

I installed Docker as recommended from the repo: [instructions](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/)

Other plugins don't work either (`docker compose` is not recognized either). Even then, `docker info` shows

```
  buildx: Docker Buildx (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v0.10.2
    Path:     /home/jpartanen/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-buildx
  compose: Docker Compose (Docker Inc.)
    Version:  v2.16.0
    Path:     /home/jpartanen/.docker/cli-plugins/docker-compose
  scan: Docker Scan (Docker Inc.)
```

Docker runs without sudo with the help of the `docker` user group, as explained in [linux-postinstall](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/linux-postinstall/). I want to run plugins without sudo as well.

I've reinstalled Docker and rebooted the machine without any change.
What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Make the plugins runnable for docker by creating a link:

```
ln -s /usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/ ~/.docker/cli-plugins
```

The command not being recognized by Docker is extra confusing because of the mismatch in commands, `build` vs `buildx`. This is because [Docker Engine 23.0](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/23.0/#new) set Buildx and BuildKit as the default builder on Linux. `docker build` is aliased to `docker buildx build`.

As for running without sudo, the problem is possibly caused by the plugins being installed in the wrong place. On my machine, running the command

```
sudo apt-get install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-buildx-plugin docker-compose-plugin
```

installs the plugins in `/usr/libexec/docker/cli-plugins/`, whereas as laid out [here](https://docs.docker.com/build/install-buildx/), the plugins are usable from `$HOME/.docker/cli-plugins` (without sudoing).

A somewhat robust solution is to create a link as laid out above.

Answer (score 1):

The [doc page about Docker Engine 23.0](https://docs.docker.com/engine/release-notes/23.0/#new) also mention a flag to use the legacy builder:

```
DOCKER_BUILDKIT=0
```

This worked for me